# Why does my yarn.lock file have more dependencies than my package.json file?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, yarnpkg

So I'm using yarn on a project but for some reason, my yarn.lock file has 300+ more dependencies than my package.json file. So if I pull the project to another server and run `yarn install`, it ends up installing the 300+ packages instead of just the 9 that I want that are in my package.json file.

Does anyone have any idea why this is? I have no clue as to how those other packages even got listed in the yarn.lock file. How do I get those other listings in the yarn.lock file to be removed?

Comment: They are dependencies of dependencies, and dependencies of dependencies of dependencies and so forth.

Comment: `package.json` lists only your *direct* dependencies, whereas `yarn.lock` also lists the dependencies of your dependencies, recursively.

Comment: "In order to get consistent installs across machines, Yarn needs more information than the dependencies you configure in your package.json. Yarn needs to store exactly which versions of each dependency were installed." A simple search on the internet would have answered your question

Comment: Thanks for the info everyone. Still seems insane to me that 9 packages need 300+ other sub-dependencies which I don't even have/use on the initial server I initiated it on. Also, @FabioAntunes, I did a simple search and didn't find my answer, hence the asked question. No need to be rude.